# Macro Filter Column by two different values - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, filter

There's a few questions on this topic. I've tried a few ways and can't seem to get it working.

I've got an `auto-copy` `script` working that takes specific values from one `sheet` and `copies` them to another `sheet`. This works fine if I `copy` on one value but I cant get it to work when adding a second value. So copy value1 or value2. Below is my `code`

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()
    Dim rng As Range, sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Worksheets("LOG")
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("P Or A")

    sht2.UsedRange.ClearContents

    With Intersect(sht1.Columns("B:BP"), sht1.UsedRange)
        .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False ' unhide columns
        If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="P"
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="A"
```

Bassed off other questions, I have tried to add the following:

```
1) Operator:=xlFilterValues,
2) Operator:=xlOr,
```

But it doesn't work. Is something else hindering the script?

Comment: I'd suggest using the macro recorder to record the steps you take as you perform  the task manually, and then you can edit the code that Excel generates to fine tune it as necessary.  See: [**Recording a Macro to Generate Code**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code) and [**Revising Recorded Visual Basic Macros**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros).

Comment: Thanks @ashleedawg. I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

From my knowledge, you can only use the filter option for up to 2 criteria. Anything outside of that you need arrays..

To do this, I assume your headers are in the range B:BP on row 1. and the field you want to filter on is col B

```
sht1.Range("B1:BP1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="P", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="A"
```

Give that a go..  Change the range/headers where aplicable and also the field number has to change for which col you are basing the filter on.

Comment: Thanks @alowflyingpig. I'll give that a go. It should be `Or` though. So `A` or `P`

Comment: Field:=1 for B column in Range("B1:BP1").

Comment: buggr, missed that sorry.. updated answer with field and or. Field always start from the first col in range.

Comment: So the values are just in Column B sorry. I athen copy all rows from Column B:BP when values in Col B = A or P

Comment: No dice mate. It just creates filters in the top row of sheet 1

Comment: @JPA0888 That is correct. Your code above shows the filter required is on `sht1.range` My answer provides details on where your headers are and also to amend the formula if required.